# Set new document after transaction in firebase admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating an API that check counter value, increment by one and after that creates new documents in document's collection. For that purpose I'm using `runTransaction()`.

And I'm running into problem. Transactions works as expected, checks counter value and after that increment it by one. But after that, when I try to set new document, I get error (empty object) and I can't do that. I think there can be bad my used logic, so I need your advice where I am wrong.

```
const db = admin.firestore()

const couterRef = db.collection('invoices').doc('invoices_doc')

let counterValue = 0

    // check last invoice counter number and increment by 1
    return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
      return transaction
        .get(couterRef)
        .then((counter) => {
          counterValue = counter.data().counter + 1
          // Update counter
          return transaction.update(couterRef, { counter: counterValue })
        })
        .catch((error) => response.status(200).send({ status: 'TRANSACTION ERROR', error }))
    })
      .then(() => {
        // Create new invoice document
        couterRef.collection('invoices').doc(counterValue).set({
           series: 'SS',
           series_nr: counterValue
        })
        .then(() => response.status(200).send({ status: 'OK' }))
        .catch((error) => response.status(200).send({ status: 'DOCUMENT SET ERROR', error }))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        response.status(200).send({ status: 'RUN TRANSACTION ERROR', error })
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested your code but the problem most probably comes from the fact that **you modify the application state inside of your transaction functions**, which is something you must avoid. There is a [specific section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions) about this problem in the documentation.

You need to pass the new value of `counterValue` **out of your transaction function**, as follows:

```
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const couterRef = db.collection('invoices').doc('invoices_doc');

  // let counterValue = 0  Remove this line

  return db
    .runTransaction((transaction) => {
      return transaction.get(couterRef).then((counter) => {
        const counterValue = counter.data().counter + 1;
          // See the changes below !!
        transaction.update(couterRef, { counter: counterValue });  // Actually, this in not an asynchronous operation
        return counterValue;  // We pass the new value of counterValue out of the transaction function
      });
    })
    .then((counterValue) => {
      // Create new invoice document
      couterRef.collection('invoices').doc(counterValue.toString(10)).set({
        series: 'SS',   // you missed a ,
        series_nr: counterValue,
      });
    })
    .then(() => response.status(200).send({ status: 'OK' }))
    .catch((error) => {
      response.status(200).send({ status: 'RUN TRANSACTION ERROR', error });
    });
```

Also, in your HTTPS Cloud Function, don't send the response back to the client from WITHIN the Transaction: this is also an application state modification and shall not be done from within the transaction.

Similarly, don't include `catch` blocks in the `then` blocks: add a `catch` block **only once** at the end of the [promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#error_propagation). If you want to deal with different error types in this unique `catch` block, just throw errors with different error messages and decide, in the `catch` block, what to do depending on the message. Alternatively you can create some subclasses of the Error class.

---

Having said all of that, since your transaction only impacts one document and only increments a counter, you could very well use the [`FieldValue.increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) method, which is atomic. See this Firebase [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Renaud, you made my code much cleaner. And in some way helped me to find a real reason why I always got an error when tried to create new document. I find out that main problem was `counterValue` variable. This variable gives me back a `number` not `string`, so you can't set new document with number, you must change it to string before.

Comment: Glad I could help you! True you have to convert it to a String, I didn't catch this one since I didn't test the code ;-) I'll adapt the answer accordingly.